# What would be the inferred type of my function here?

Tags: f#

I am wondering why F# compiler allows the following

```
type MyMath() =
 member this.Add a b = a + b
```

What would be the type of Add method and its arguments ? If I compiled this into the Library and try to use it in C# what types of arguments it is going to expect ?

Shouldn't the F# require you to explicitly specify types when it comes to Methods of classes ?

Comment: ILSpy is also a great tool for stuff like this - you can decompile into IL or C# (or even VB.NET :D)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can enter the code in F# interactive and see the inferred type yourself:

```
> type MyMath() =
    member this.Add a b = a + b;;

type MyMath =
  class
    new : unit -> MyMath
    member Add : a:int -> b:int -> int
  end
```

Here, the compiler uses default type for the `+` operator which is `int`. The operator can be used with other types, but the inference uses `int` as the default. You can use type annotations, but you are not required to do that if you are happy with the inferred type.

In general, you can use type annotations in F# to specify types if you want to, but in many cases, the inferred type will be exactly what you want, so you do not have to make the code more verbose, if the inference behaves as expected.

Of course, if you were writing some library and wanted to be super careful about changing the API, then you might want to use type annotations (or you can add F# Interface file `.fsi`)

Answer (score 2):

F# Interactive is your friend:

```
type MyMath =
  class
    new : unit -> MyMath
    member Add : a:int -> b:int -> int
  end
```

Comment: I do not have VS, using ideone.com that has no FSI. Thank you for suggestion.

Comment: You can also try http://www.tryfsharp.org, which requires Silverlight, but then it gives you fully-powered F# editor with F# Interactive...